# How to fix 'not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)' error

Tags: python-3.7

I can't for some reason run the code because it says I need two values when I only need one. How to I get past that?

I have tried to delete the value but all I got was an error.

```
def read_from_file():
    with open("capital_data.txt") as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            country, city = line.split("/")
            the_world[country] = city



ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

I don't know what else to put; I don't have any other ideas.

**** Problem Rectified, credits to Gino Mempin

Comment: What do you mean by "when I only need one"?  Because you clearly use both of them in the next line.

Comment: Can you provide us the full stacktrace

Comment: Sorry, I can't do that, I have trouble with the copy and pasting(my computer is going haywire). I'll have to type it all out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is referring to this line:

```
country, city = line.split("/")
```

[`split("/")`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) returns a `list` containing the words from the string `line`, split using the `/` character. For example, if `line` is "japan/tokyo", then `line.split("/")` will return the list

```
['japan', 'tokyo']
```

If there is no `/` character, then the list will just contain 1 element. For example if `line` is "japan,tokyo", splitting it will just return

```
['japan,tokyo']
```

What is happening with `country, city = ...` is called **list unpacking**, meaning the 1st element is saved to `country` and the 2nd element of the list is saved to `city`. If your list is is `['japan', 'tokyo']`, then `country` will get "japan" and `city` will get "tokyo". If the number of elements in the right-hand side list does not match the left-hand side variables, you will get a "**not enough values to unpack**" error.

Now, I cannot see what's in capital_data.txt, but most probably, the `line`'s from your file does not have a `/` delimiter (ex. "japan, tokyo"). So `split`-ing the line with `/` results in just 1 list element ("**got 1**"), but the left-hand side has 2 variables ("**expected 2**").

To get past that, you need to match your file reader code with your actual file format, such as maybe using the correct delimiter (replacing `/`).