# Issue with Alarm Function in making my Clock

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have a major issue with my alarm function in the clock I'm making in Python, a Tkinter error regarding two split functions in my code. I printed out the split components in both cases, and all of them seemed to split properly. I do not know what the issue is.

Here is the code

```
def alarm():
    if toggledtime == "AM/PM":
            mainAMPM_time = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M %p")
            alarm_timeAMPMmain = get_alarm_time_entry.get()
            alarm_timeAMPM,alarm_period= alarm_timeAMPMmain.split(' ')
            alarm_hourAMPM, alarm_minutesAMPM = alarm_timeAMPM.split(':')
            main_timeAMPM,main_period = mainAMPM_time.split(' ')
            main_hourAMPM, main_minutesAMPM = main_timeAMPM.split(':')
            print(alarm_timeAMPMmain)
            print()
            print(alarm_hourAMPM)
            print(alarm_minutesAMPM)
            print(alarm_period)
            print()
    else:        
            mainMilitary_time= dt.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
            alarm_timeMilitarymain = get_alarm_time_entry.get()
            alarm_hourMilitary, alarm_minutesMilitary = alarm_timeMilitarymain.split(':')
            main_hourMilitary, main_minutesMilitary = mainMilitary_time.split(':')
            print(alarm_timeMilitarymain)
            print()
            print(alarm_hourMilitary)
            print(alarm_minutesMilitary)
            print()
```

And here is both errors I get. They are similar Tkinter Errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/arnabd/miniconda3/envs/PythonEnV2/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", 
 line 1892, in __call__
       return self.func(*args)
 File "/home/arnabd/miniconda3/envs/PythonEnV2/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", 
 line 814, in callit
       func(*args)
 File "/home/arnabd/Documents/PythonVSCODEProjects/Clock.py", line 55, in alarm
    alarm_timeAMPM,alarm_period= alarm_timeAMPMmain.split(' ')
    ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/arnabd/miniconda3/envs/PythonEnV2/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", 
  line 1892, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
 File "/home/arnabd/miniconda3/envs/PythonEnV2/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", 
  line 814, in callit
        func(*args)
 File "/home/arnabd/Documents/PythonVSCODEProjects/Clock.py", line 62, in alarm
      alarm_hourMilitary, alarm_minutesMilitary = alarm_timeMilitarymain.split(':')
    ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Here is the output from those print statements:

```
10:24 AM

10

24

AM



10

17

10:17
```

Edit: I tried other delimiters and rechecked the output of my code to ensure I am using the right one. I want to say that the alarm actually starts, but does not produce a noise that I coded in. I'll put in the code for that.

```
if toggledtime == "AM/PM":
     if int(alarm_hourAMPM) == int(main_hour) and int(alarm_minutesAMPM) == int(main_minutesAMPM) and alarm_period == main_period:
            for i in range(3):
               alarm_status_label.config(text='Time Is Up')
               print("\a")
            get_alarm_time_entry.config(state='enabled')        
            set_alarm_button.config(state='enabled')
            get_alarm_time_entry.delete(0,END)
            alarm_status_label.config(text = '')

     else:
            alarm_status_label.config(text='Alarm Has Started')
            get_alarm_time_entry.config(state='disabled')
            set_alarm_button.config(state='disabled')        
     alarm_status_label.after(1000, alarm)

    else:
     if int(alarm_hourMilitary) == int(main_hourMilitary) and int(alarm_minutesMilitary) == int(main_minutesMilitary):
            for i in range(3):
               alarm_status_label.config(text='Time Is Up')
               print("\a")
            get_alarm_time_entry.config(state='enabled')        
            set_alarm_button.config(state='enabled')
            get_alarm_time_entry.delete(0,END)
            alarm_status_label.config(text = '')

     else:
            alarm_status_label.config(text='Alarm Has Started')
            get_alarm_time_entry.config(state='disabled')
            set_alarm_button.config(state='disabled')        
     alarm_status_label.after(1000, alarm)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix 'not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57060829/how-to-fix-not-enough-values-to-unpack-expected-2-got-1-error)

Comment: Your problem seems to be coming from `get_alarm_time_entry.get()`. What ever user is entered here is probably the cause.